Randomized quantile residuals in this paper
I am reading the article "The Unit-improved second-degree Lindley distribution: inference and regression modeling" by Emrah Altun and Gauss M. Cordeiro. And I want to replicate one of their results. I am trying to make the randomized quantile residuals plot for the Beta regression, but I am not getting the same results. They have this plot
$\hskip2in$ 
But I get

using qqPlot and residuals. And at least visually they don't look alike, for example there is a value of approximately -3, but in my case there isn't. My code is
y = c(2.640, 0.596, 0.680, 2.190, 4.560, 2.140, 0.410, 
                  0.530, 0.750, 0.280, 4.390, 3.390, 5.190, 0.800, 2.160, 
                  2.640, 0.060, 2.549, 0.930, 0.310, 0.540, 7.750, 0.470, 
                  2.810, 1.760, 3.170, 1.760, 1.010, 0.990, 1.318, 0.550, 
                  0.040, 1.374, 2.890)
y = y/100
x = c(30.78, 57.87, 121.52, 90.17, 45.39, 11.08, 55.92, 51.54, 
                56.31, 43.34, 11.64, 20.85, 21.99, 276.22, 28.81, 27.56, 
                30.6, 21.02, 5.93, 7.24, 380.1, 15.76, 305.44, 8.94, 
                48.05, 5.41, 23.68, 3.56, 14.53, 41.9, 71.7, 162.75, 
                61.86, 40.43)
x = x/100
beta_model = betareg(y ~  x)
r_i = residuals(beta_model, type = "quantile")
car::qqPlot(r_i, main = "Beta", ylab = "r_i")

I would appreciate any help or references regarding this topic.

I get the same results with the qqrplot() function from topmodels (https://topmodels.r-forge.r-project.org/) compared to qqPlot() from car. Is the graphic for the paper really for a standard beta regression? Or have they modified something there?

Is the graph in the paper is properly aligned, so that the diagonal line is the y = x line? Otherwise comparisons with other implementation would be challenging.

After actually looking at the paper, they fit the standard beta regression: we can check that they report the same results we get with summary(beta_model). So there must be a difference in how they calculate the quantile residuals. You can get a QQ plot closer to the one in the article with r_i <- residuals(beta_model, type = "weighted"). The most straightforward way to learn what the auhors did is to write to them & ask them to share their code.

Thanks @dipetkov for taking the time to read and corroborate the results.  I will do as you suggest, and thank you very much for replying. Have you by any chance been in a similar situation? Where you had to ask the authors about their results? Regards!

Yes, I've contacted an author about a small result in their paper that didn't quite add up. That happened as a result of another CV question. (If you are interested, you can read about it here. After a bit more staring at QQ plots I'm almost sure that what happened is that 6A and 6C are actually the same graph, so the mistake occurred in putting Figure 6 together.

Good idea to contact the authors. I've also done this several time successfully (albeit sometimes also insuccessfully). So fingers crossed. Regaring the residual types: Possibly they mixed up "quantile" which is the default type since version 3.2-0 and "sweighted2" which was the default in previous version.
